# Adding Listview layout causes root view to shrink

Tags: android, listview, dialogfragment

I'm having a problem which is hard to describe, but I'll do my best.

In my app I'm showing a list of songs in a DialogFragment (which displays above the other components)

[image]

When I click the 'eye'-icon on the right of a song, a window pops up with the information about that song

[image]

So far everything works fine. But when I add a Listview component at the bottom of that popup windows layout, this windows suddenly shrinks. The popup window does not get out of the boundaries of the underlying dialog fragment I suppose for some reason.

So I just added

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_more_song_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

[image]

Just adding a list causes the new window to stop going outside the boundaries of the underlying DialogFragment, so it appears.

Can someone tell me why this happens? And how I can solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you might want to look into RecyclerView